# How to serialize / deserialize a double value independent of culture

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

How can I serialize / deserialize a double value so that it can be read and written on systems with different decimal point symbols?

Write:

```
double d;
d.ToString();
```

Read:

```
double d = (double)Convert.ChangeType(serialized_value, new Double().GetType());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify an invariant format provider

```
double d = 2.0;

var invariantString = Convert.ToString(d, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var d2 = Convert.ToDouble(invariantString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: that does not work for RU-ru culture.

example:

var str = "0,6";
var d2 = Convert.ToDouble(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// here d2 is "6.0" not "0.6"